# Timeout while uploading large files in GeoNode / GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, time, geonode

I am getting timeout while uploading large files in GeoNode ( System Configuration : GeoNode 3.1.0 , GeoServer 2.16.2 installed on Ubuntu 18.04. ).

I tried compressing large files to decrease their size (E.g. `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "PREDICTOR=2" uncompressed.tiff compressed.tiff` ), this helped for some cases only. But I have other files which are still large.

So I wish to increase the timeout. But, I could not find some exact reference which can guide me to increase the timeout for this scenario.
While exploring geonode/geoserver settings, I found different timeout settings and tried to increase timeout period in different settings as follows:

1. Timeout increased in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

   - `keepalive_timeout` increased to `300` from `65`
2. Timeout increased in GeoNode UWSGI config
   (`/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/geonode.ini`)

   - `env = OGC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT` increaded to `600` from `60`.
   - `harakiri` increased to `600` from `300`

Still timeout occurs while uploading large files. Is there some settings I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using `http-socket` on your `geonode.ini`, try adding the following parameters to the NGINX location

```
  proxy_connect_timeout       600;
  proxy_send_timeout          600;
  proxy_read_timeout          600;
  send_timeout                600;
  proxy_redirect              off;
  proxy_set_header            Host $host;
  proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  proxy_pass http://$upstream;
```

2. Try updating the `geonode.ini` as follows

```
env = OGC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT=30
env = OGC_REQUEST_MAX_RETRIES=1
env = OGC_REQUEST_BACKOFF_FACTOR=0.3
env = OGC_REQUEST_POOL_MAXSIZE=10
env = OGC_REQUEST_POOL_CONNECTIONS=10
env = GEONODE_DB_CONN_MAX_AGE=0
env = GEONODE_DB_CONN_TOUT=5
```

If are still having problems, you could try to revise the `cheaper` on `geonode.ini` parameters in the case you are using them, as an instance, try tweaking the follwoing params:

```
max-requests = 1000                  ; Restart workers after this many requests
max-worker-lifetime = 3600           ; Restart workers after this many seconds
reload-on-rss = 2048                 ; Restart workers after this much resident memory
worker-reload-mercy = 60             ; How long to wait before forcefully killing workers
```